# How to exclude ModSecurity rules by hostname?

Tags: firewall, mod-security, web-application-firewall

I'm using [OWASP core rule set 3.2.0](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset) set up with [ModSecurity 3.0.4](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) and [ModSecurity-nginx](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx).

If I have a rule exclusion like this, in `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf`:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /api.php" \
     "id:1015,\
     phase:2,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     ctl:ruleRemoveById=941160"
```

How do I also limit this exclusion to a specific hostname? For example, `wiki.example.com`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `REQUEST_HEADERS:Host` chained with `REQUEST_URI` does the trick, but gets harder to maintain, if there are several sites that either need or don't need the exclusion. Therefore, an alternative solution would be **disabling the rules on the Nginx configuration** for the virtualhost, instead.

It's possible to disable some rules using [`modsecurity_rules`](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx#modsecurity_rules) inside specific `server` & `location`:

```
server {
    server_name wiki.example.com;
    modsecurity on;
    . . .

    location /api.php {
        modsecurity_rules '
            SecRuleRemoveById 941160
        ';
    }
}
```

---

The same is possible with **Apache**, too, as some Apache users may later find this question based on its title. With Apache, you can use `SecRuleRemoveById` / `modsecurity_rules` directives

- inside `VirtualHost` and `Location` or `LocationMatch`:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName wiki.example.com
      . . .

      <LocationMatch "^/api.php">
          <IfModule security2_module>
              SecRuleRemoveById 941160
          </IfModule>
          <IfModule security3_module>
              modsecurity_rules 'SecRuleRemoveById 941160'
          </IfModule>
      </LocationMatch>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- or, although [not recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when), even with `.htaccess`:

  ```
  <IfModule security2_module>
      <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api.php#">
          SecRuleRemoveById 941160
      </If>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule security3_module>
      <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api.php#">
          modsecurity_rules 'SecRuleRemoveById 941160'
      </If>
  </IfModule>
  ```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! This is definitely clearer and more maintainable, without having to mess around with custom rule IDs. I have another question,  but it's more of a general nginx config question. I could ask this elsewhere. With these new location blocks, I need to duplicate some configuration in order for my server to still serve these routes dynamically, and not give a 404 after ignoring the ModSec rule. See the comments in my config here: https://paste.victor.computer/By-xY5Ts8

Comment: It's best you ask another question on that!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use `REQUEST_HEADERS:Host` with [chain](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#chain), like this:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "wiki.example.com" \
     "id:1017,\
     phase:2,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     chain"
     SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /api.php" \
         "ctl:ruleRemoveById= 941160"
```